# How do I convert a binary certificate to x509?

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

I have a server certificate that I want to trust. But java doesn't accept it in this code. How do I convert the certificate to x509?

```
 return (Collection<X509Certificate>) CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
                        .generateCertificates(new ByteArrayInputStream(cert.getBytes()));
```

cert:

0‚я0‚з \±
®FPљF·1ЪуAяф0
*†H†ч
0Ѓ•10  UGB10UGreater Manchester10USalford10U
Sectigo Limited1=0;U4Sectigo RSA Organization Validation Secure Server CA0
210913000000Z
221014235959Z0e10   URU10
UMoskva10U

PJSC MTS Bank10 UIT1 0Utestpayments.mtsbank.ru0‚"0
*†H†ч
‚ 0‚
‚ БLR€fЁВGK}ЧІЅџ¬‡ »FйЎNлNЕї¦жШЪvДhг,Чb‘ђ‰(фњkЬ4эµoµQS¶4¦9
0bц±€ks%®xЇҐ4ўжк¦…ФnДF†Ж]b{L|Ш7’ЪmIЈvўДЉ„ym¶T\ьЛСx)Ѓ€~х’Ѓiр·юЎKЦ*fРћ'-ѓКђђЂ)И;\ЙБ/ФфЂ&C®¤Л
°‚M;щн_ 1~#JЅJРЯЖЈ1Ю•н)Ќµdґnы–оШ9:4њSН¬ъИЊ­ь.уЈ8чІ   ИЄФ9йѕфqj–Эа`о=KДњX%Р§я~A7± Ј‚x0‚t0U#0ЂЩЦ%'gщ1ВICЩ06DЊl©Oл0UзEКЁуІ‡Sґ«&›И 9    S :50Uя 0Uя0 0U%0++0JU C0A05+І10%0#+https://sectigo.com/CPS0gЃ0ZUS0Q0O M K†Ihttp://crl.sectigo.com/SectigoRSAOrganizationValidationSecureServerCA.crl0ЃЉ+~0|0U+0†Ihttp://crt.sectigo.com/SectigoRSAOrganizationValidationSecureServerCA.crt0#+0†http://ocsp.sectigo.com0?U806‚testpayments.mtsbank.ru‚www.testpayments.mtsbank.ru0‚} +Цy‚m‚ig u FҐUлuъ‘ 0µў‰iфу},AtѕэIё…«тьpюmG  {Ю|ъ]   F0D &я$„ѕT<ЎюЯC` jД‘ћDЇ‚вЕЏWјV}д °Љ)n›мРДtщq©,mІGќеЬ–Pjп–®e v AИК±Я"FJЖЎ:   B‡^N1‹ллKЗhрђb–ц  {Ю|ъ"   G0E! Я55eЮьэW;ыФ/µр·ћІNцw*\¤OGќ
M 50МЖіT{жМ‘П=ЧНHэД9v‚UOеСуЧ$ v )yѕрћ99!рVsџcҐwеѕW}њ `шщM]&\%]З„  {Ю|щэ   G0E gЫx`;·ґш1шнГ*Z“ЬЄЪ2ы••vIоhЮ! чxтЁ‹Е–ќµ\©mШ= 6ўчеЧ{Ўь:кё6лЄг0
*†H†ч
‚ Ћz™ЋQZп^чZVеVцOS;‰?Њ4Щї;Д8?•1ЫА:rZўПгdфИ zTдt3¦СЊҐБ™»g[R¦oаOH;¬Ъw{†х*ІDuљ,1Кc­ЂЂ5НAR
6СаГ ќщџэБДСЊ-ё“fќCs’ПСЫ%иаѕ‹[5с|Т~FН§b4эKйЃ39&нџЫ’Т2>Щид8”Ќtп9–-bўоbRі›]Љ9аNgцЄ7.ЁOЯ[)©Фµх.   ®тмҐ{µ¦`·|оьуР¬]сЂІv9ЋWХH›xаrЁУя»zЛ_рJ.З;yS#}Ё

I tried to do so but failed:

OpenSSL> x509 -in Z:\cert.cer -out Z:\cert12.pem
unable to load certificate
10976:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:686:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
error in x509

Comment: It appears `cert` is a String.  In Java, Strings cannot hold binary data.  You corrupted your binary data when you tried to store it in a String.  Calling `getBytes()` will not give you the same data the file held originally.

Answer (score -2):

Encoded in base64 through the file and the code passed

https://www.base64encode.org/